# How to place ships based on their length into 2d array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am working on this battleship project and cannot figure out how to place ships based on their length. I can only place one ship at the moment. Can't figure out how to place ships vertical or horizontal.

```js
const createShip = (shipLength, name) => {
  let hits = 0
  let sunk = false

  function getLength() {
    return this.shipLength
  }

  function hit() {
    hits += 1
    return hits
  }

  function isSunk() {
    if (hits >= shipLength) {
      sunk = true
      return sunk
    }
    sunk = false
    return sunk
  }
  return {
    getLength,
    hit,
    isSunk,
    shipLength,
    name
  }
}

const Gameboard = () => {
  const rows = 10
  const columns = 10
  const board = []

  console.log(board)

  // Need to reduce array amount to a single value
  const cellCount = board.reduce((row, col) => row + col.length, 0)

  const getBoard = () => [...board]

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i += 1) {
    board[i] = []
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j += 1) {
      board[i][j] = null
    }
  }

  const placeShip = (x, y, ship, direction) => {
    // Loop through gameboard
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i += 1) {
      for (let j = 0; j < board[i].length; j += 1) {
        board[x][y] = ship.name
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    placeShip,
    getBoard,
    cellCount
  }
}

const gameboard = Gameboard()
const testShip = createShip(3, "Boat")


gameboard.placeShip(2, 4, testShip)
```

For example instead of placing one ship like so :

```js
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, SHIP, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Ships can be placed based on their length like so :

```js
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, SHIP, SHIP, SHIP, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, SHIP, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, SHIP, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
[null, SHIP, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Comment: My thought process is since I have to look over a game board or in other words scan the board to see if a ship has been placed or not. That is was the nested loops are for. @Yogi

Comment: So let's do a bit of thinking: `x` and `y` are the start position of the new ship, right? First of all, you have to check, whether there all relevant positions are empty. Ie you have to iterate over the ship's length and increment either the `x` or `y`© coordinate, depending on the direction. Every coordinate has to be empty and you must not go over the border. If that's ok, do the same loop again, but now update the matrix. You can also of course update the matrix in the first loop. But then you will have to reverse your changes, if the ship doesn't fit